GitHub Actions Failed to Deploy changes to Heroku (python application)
I am using GitHub Actions to Deploy my python to Heroku.
Container pushed.
Releasing container...
›   Warning: Our terms of service have changed:
›   https://dashboard.heroku.com/terms-of-service
›   Error: This command is for Docker apps only. Switch stacks by running
›   heroku stack:set container. Or, to deploy *** with heroku-22, run
›   git push heroku main instead.
Error: Releasing docker container failed.
Error: undefined

...okay? Did you read that error message? What part is unclear? Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

@user27012712 As Chris says, the error message is pretty clear in that it’s telling you the command is for Docker apps only, and you seem to be trying to push a non-Docker app. So, provide more details such as what command you’re actually trying to run in GitHub Actions; and the full error message, formatted.
